# Laravel faker - loop to add records to simulate version control

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, faker, laravel-seeding

I am using faker to seed my DB.

```
$factory->define(App\Product::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    $campaign = factory(App\Campaign::class)->create();
    $size= $faker->randomElement($array = array ('728x90','300x250','315x315', '715x425', '750x650'));


    return [
        'campaign_id' => $campaign->campaign_name,
        'size' => $size,
        'product_id' => $campaign->campaign_name."_".$size,
        'version' => $faker->randomElement($array = array ('1','2','3', '4', '5')),


    ];
});
```

The bit I am interested in is the version field. What I would like to do is generate a random number between 1 and 5 and  then enter that number of records in the database,

So a product can have been 1 and 5 entries depending on the number of 'versions' which have bene created.

Is this possible?

I tried a simple for loop around the return array with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, you want to create multiple entries for the same product with different versions. The Model factory can be used to create a single model entry. You can use the faker directly in the seeder and achieve what you are expecting.

```
$campaign = factory(App\Campaign::class)->create();
$size= $faker->randomElement($array = array ('728x90','300x250','315x315', '715x425', '750x650'))

$max_version = $faker->randomElement($array = array ('1','2','3', '4', '5'));

for ($version=0; $version < $max_version; $version++) { 
    Product::create([
        'campaign_id' => $campaign->campaign_name,
        'size' => $size,
        'product_id' => $campaign->campaign_name."_".$size,
        'version' => $version,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solutions is to create factory method (or trait) in your test class, something like this, you'll get the point :)

```
public function createProduct()
{
    $product = factory(Product::class)->create();

    foreach(range(0, $product->version) as $i) {
        factory(Version::class)->create([
            'product_id' => $product->id
        ]);
    }

    return $product;
}
```